# How to process colon(:) while reading TXT file

Tags: csv, dataframe

The original TXT file's shape is like this.

```
1:

A1 B1 C1 
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
.
.
2:

A1 B1 C1 
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
.
.
```

and I want to transform it to CSV file with shape ( adding feature )

```
1 A1 B1 C1 
1 A2 B2 C2
1 A3 B3 C3
.
.
2 A1 B1 C1 
2 A2 B2 C2
2 A3 B3 C3
.
.
.
```

How could I transform like this way..

Thanks for editing .

A, B, C each are features

Comment: Are the `"."` part of the filed after row `A3` ? If not can you edit your question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

If the input is

```
1:

A1 B1 C1 
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
2:

A1 B1 C1 
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
```

you can run

```
<input.csv | grep -Pv '(:|^$)'
```

to have

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
```